# Entity Type Manager: How to retrieve webform entries with webform_submission_data conditions

Tags: webforms

I would like to get the webform entries submitted by a user with a particular webform_submission_data field value. E.g. field_account_type = "normal"

How can I supply such a condition?

```
$submission_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');
$submissions = $submission_storage->loadByProperties([
  'webform_id' => 'my_form_id', 
  'uid' => $uid,
  'field_account_type' => 'normal' // Not found exception!
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you can query webform fields like entity fields, but it should be possible in an SQL select query:

```
$submission_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');

$query = \Drupal::database()->select('webform_submission_data')
  ->fields('webform_submission_data', ['sid'])
  ->condition('webform_id', 'my_form_id')
  ->condition('name', 'field_account_type')
  ->condition('value', 'normal')
  ->distinct();

$ids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

$submissions = $submission_storage->loadMultiple($ids);
```

If you want to query the uid from the main table too, join both tables:

```
$submission_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');

$query = \Drupal::database()->select('webform_submission_data', 'd');
$query->join('webform_submission', 's', 'd.sid = s.sid');
$query->fields('d', ['sid'])
  ->condition('d.webform_id', 'my_form_id')
  ->condition('s.uid', $uid)
  ->condition('d.name', 'field_account_type')
  ->condition('d.value', 'normal')
  ->distinct();

$ids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

$submissions = $submission_storage->loadMultiple($ids);
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the static query part, been pulling my head on how to include the uid on the entity query. I guess you have to put everything in the static query then.